# How can I install pcre-light on OS X without root access?

Tags: macos, haskell, pcre, cabal

I'm working on a shared system where I don't have root access, but where the admins have installed the Haskell Platform. Most Cabal packages install perfectly happily, but I need a library with a dependency on `pcre-light`, which of course depends on the C library `pcre`. Is there an easy way to install `pcre` under `$HOME` so that I can get on with my work?

Answer (score 1):

As it happens, Homebrew works perfectly well from inside `$HOME`:

http://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-install-the-homebrew-package-management-utility-locally-on-mac-osx/

In short, you can install Homebrew simply by cloning the GitHub repo into `$HOME`, then adding `$HOME/homebrew/bin` to your `$PATH`. Then you can just say:

```
$ brew install pcre
```

Then tweak `$HOME/.cabal/config` like so:

```
extra-include-dirs: $HOME/homebrew/include
extra-lib-dirs: $HOME/homebrew/lib
```

(but use the actual directory instead of `$HOME`). Now `cabal install pcre-light` should work normally.